# Proving that a Prime Power $p^{k}$ is a Divisor of $a^{p-1} - 1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, pseudoprimes

Let $n$ be a Fermat-pseudoprime with respect to $a$. Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $n$ and let $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Show that if $p^k\mid n$, then $p^k\mid (a^{p-1}-1)$.

I tried showing this as follows. It holds that $2^{n-1}\equiv 1\mod n$. And since $p^k\mid n$, it will also hold that $2^{n-1}\equiv 1\mod p^k$. So this is where I get stuck, since I want to reduce the power of 2 from $n-1$ to $p-1$.

Comment: Are you sure the conclusion is true? Possible counter-examples are hard to check because of the size of the numbers involved. But it seems to me that your conclusion is true for a certain class of primes---but before I spend more time on it, I would like to know if you are certain that your proposition is true as stated.

Comment: The conclusion is true (according to my professor at least)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the structure of the group $G=\Bbb{Z}_{p^k}^*$. More specifically from the fact that $G$ is cyclic of order $p^{k-1}(p-1)$.

It is clear that $a$ must be coprime to $p$, so we can think of $a$ as an element of $G$.
Let $m$ be the order of $a$ in this group. By Lagrange's theorem $m\mid p^{k-1}(p-1)$.
On the other hand we know that $a^{n-1}\equiv1\pmod{p^k}$, so $m$ must also be a factor of $n-1$.

Getting warmer! As $p^k\mid n$, it follows that $p\nmid n-1$. Therefore also $p\nmid m$.
This means that $m$ must be a factor of $p-1$, which is exactly what is required.

Comment: Ok, cyclicity of $G$ was not needed. Meaning that the argument also goes through when $p=2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a really neat answer and I can fully comprehend it.